# What is the minimal polynomial of $T$ if $Ker(T)=Im(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Its well know that if $Ker(T)=Im(T)$ for a linear transformation $T$ on a finite vector space $V$. Then The dimension of $V$ is even.

Now I have a question related to the minimal polynomial to this transformation; I know its equal to $x^2$ but not sure where comes from. 
any help appreciated.

Okay:- I know if $T(V)=\lambda V=0$ implies to $\lambda=0$ but why there is square in the minimal polynomial?

Comment: You mean finite _dimensional_ vector space. Curiously (unless you are working over a finite field) the only finite vector spaces are those of dimension $0$, and your statement fails _precisely_ for that case (the hypothesis for $T$ is trivially satisfied when $\dim(V)=0$, but the minimal polynomial of $T$ will be $1$ rather than $x^2$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $T$ is an operator for which $\ker T = \operatorname{im} T$, then $T^2 = 0$:

$$T^2 x = T(Tx) = 0$$

since $T$ is acting on a vector in the image of $T$. So minimum polynomial of $T$ is a divisor of $x^2$.

Now the only divisors of $x^2$ are multiples of $x$ (or constants...), but an operator whose minimum polynomial is $x$ is the zero operator (and in fact, the only operators whose minimum polynomials are of degree $1$ are multiples of the identity operator).

Comment: Thanks. but can you give me more details about why "$T$ is acting on a vector in the image of $T$. So minimum polynomial of $T$ is a divisor of $x^2$”. I only have difficulty to understand that part ( maybe there reason is that I do not like action ).

Comment: @henry That was meant to be an explanation of why $T(Tx) = 0$. Since $Tx$ is obviously in the range of $T$ = the kernel of $T$, taking $T$ of it yields zero.

Comment: Thanks I get it now the idea of action.